# Ember.js: CollectionView individual items not being displayed

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Here is a gist containing relevant code: https://gist.github.com/mderoche/9d38393a48d5adaedb5d

I have a CollectionView hooked up to an ArrayController, and I would like to use the CollectionView to render each object in the ArrayController's content with the given itemViewClass.  In the example, the ArrayController is a book whose content is an array of chapters, the CollectionView is the thing that is to display this list of chapters, and the itemView is the view to show an individual chapter item in the CollectionView list.

I *think* that the CollectionView is getting the data it needs, because when the setTimeout() function triggers to populate the ArrayController, the emptyView template is no longer used (at the start, it IS used and displays fine).  However, instead of showing "testing" several times (a copy of the item template for each object), nothing appears at all.  According to the `didInsertElement` hook on the item view, the element *was* (allegedly) inserted into the DOM, but the 'element' property is undefined.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: why don't you use #each helper?

Comment: Is that a better way to do it than a CollectionView?  I am new to Ember, so I don't know the best practices yet.  Regardless, I'd still like to know why my current code is not working just for the sake of learning the framework.

Comment: I would use #each and #bind-attr helpers http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/displaying-a-list-of-items/ http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/binding-element-class-names/

Comment: So, I solved the problem with a blockless each helper, but I am still interested in knowing why the CollectionView strategy was broken.